# Why do newer commercial aircraft have their wingtips curved up?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing

Lately I've seen a lot of aircraft that have the wingtips curved up.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: related http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8544 and http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8556

Comment: Presumably because with composites, they can. Curving aluminium or steel would be a lot harder. With a composite wing, you can lay down the fiber in new ways.

Comment: Hey, Scottie. Just wanted to let you know that I'm closing because there is already a duplicate – with very different wording – not because it is a bad question (it's not!).

Comment: I think we shuold leave this question here.  It's a good example of [this question on meta](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/410/when-to-use-technical-terms-vs-layman-terms).  Some people might now know what winglets are, so this question will lead them there.

Comment: For drag reduction, due spilling air from the underside of the wingtips  over the top side where the pressure is lower.After that the swirling pattern of airflows is left behind. So to minimise but not eliminate them the winglets is added